# Rename admin account on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, user-accounts, administrator

Usually use a Mac, so I'm already out of my element. I got my Dell XPS fixed recently, which included a full wipe. They also (unexpectedly) updated my OS from 10 to 11.

They created a local account called "Admin." I changed the type of account to make it align with my Microsoft login. It most places, it shows my name instead of "Admin," now, which is good.

However, in certain places, it still shows "Admin." For example, in the Command Prompt, it shows `C:\Users\Admin`.

How do I change the name so that "Admin" becomes something of my choice?

Comment: Decide if you want a local account or a M$ account. Make a new useraccount with the name you want. Delete the old useraccount. Renaming is too advanced for microsoftians. People tried to invent weird workarounds, but I wouldn't recommend em https://www.lifewire.com/change-user-folder-name-in-windows-10-5114140

Comment: In cases like this where the old useracc is using 2 names, including the one you want, you may have to make a new useracc called temp, delete the old user, then make the useracc with the name you want, then delete the useracc temp. Oof. Windows is clearly superior to all other operating systems. /s

Comment: Disconnect the account from your Microsoft Account, you will be prompted to rename the profile, once you logout and login reconnect the Microsoft Account. The method a describe is the only true way to do what you want flawlessly